# Custom back button behavior doesn't navigate to specified screen

Tags: react-native

So I have a TabNavigator with multiple screen and I am trying to create a custom behavior for the back button on Android in Messages screen. This custom behavior works with console.logs, but it doesn't work when I try to navigate to the Home screen. I used a code snippet from the react-navigation docs and modified it as I needed (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-android-back-button-handling/). I want to make the `navigation.navigate('Home');` work.

**TabNavigator**

```
class Tabs extends React.Component 
{
  render()
  {
    // Create Bottom Tab Navigatior
    const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

    const { navigation } = this.props;
    return(
      <Tab.Navigator tabBar={props => <CustomTabBar {...props} />}>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Map" component={MapScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Zap" component={ZapScreen}/>
        <Tab.Screen name="Explore" component={ExploreScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Post" component={PostScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Messages" component={MessagesScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    )
  }
}
```

**Messages screen**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, StyleSheet, BackHandler } from 'react-native';
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native'
import styles from './MessagesScreenStyles';

const MessagesScreen = ({navigation}) => {

    useFocusEffect(
        React.useCallback(() => {
          const onBackPress = () => {
                console.log("onbackpress"); // This works
                navigation.navigate('Home'); // This does nothing, not even an error
          };
    
          BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onBackPress);
    
          return () =>
            BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onBackPress);
        })
    );
    return(
        <View style = {styles.container}>
            <Text>MessagesScreen</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

export default MessagesScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `navigation.navigate` method works with `Stack` screens. Try the `jump` method.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation#jumping-between-tabs

Comment: I understand now why it doesn't work. What do you mean use the jump method? The docs from your link use `navigation.navigate` as well. Please elaborate.